# Grabbing tweets with a certain hastag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

Im using jquery/JS to grab the latest tweets of a account, but I want to filter them by hashtag instead.

my getJson call is: http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/sustrans.json?count=2

I can't seem to find the documentation that says to filter these by a hastag value...

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: there is no hashtag in the text  in given link

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540618/does-the-twitter-api-allow-filtering-by-username-and-hashtag)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714471/twitter-api-display-all-tweets-with-a-certain-hashtag

Answer (score 0):

You can use the search api e.g.

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23myhashtag+from:myusername
```

But it will only return Tweets from the past 24 hours.

The alternative is to to get the whole timeline and pull out the Tweets you want.

```
var tweets = []
$.getJSON('http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/sustrans.json?callback=?', function(data){
  for(i in data) {
    if(data[i].text.indexOf('#hastag') > -1) {
      tweets.push(data[i]);
    }
  }
});
```