# How to query the Twitter search API for a username and hashtag in one request

Tags: php, api, url, search, twitter

I'm trying to make a GET request using the Twitter API which will return all tweets from a certain user with a specific hashtag. It should be as simple as including q=%23HASHTAG&from:USERNAME but unfortunately that doesn't seem to be working. It only includes the search criteria that occurs first. For instance my query is:

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from:USERNAME&%23HASHTAG&include_entities=true

Where USERNAME and HASHTAG are the username and hashtag I'm searching for. This only returns tweets from the user and does not filter them by the hashtag. If I swap them in the URL it only searches for the hashtag and not the user. Does anyone have any solutions to my problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the Twitter API allow filtering by username AND hashtag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540618/does-the-twitter-api-allow-filtering-by-username-and-hashtag)

Answer (score 0):

use the '+' operator not '&'...
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from:USERNAME+%23HASHTAG&include_entities=true